# Make a connection to a MS SQL database in the local machine

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse-plugin, virtualhost

I am trying to access a database which is located in my C drive in my local machine. I can access the data base through Microsoft SQL server Management Studio. However as the data base is not in a server my first question is "if even it's possible to access it through my java code."

-I have tried my local machine address and also the name of the server however non of them seems to be working.

```
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://DAVE-PC\\SQLEXP/"; 
    String dbName = "STORESQL";
   // String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "dave-PC\\dave";
    String password="";
     try {
     //     Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
          Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
          java.sql.Statement stm= con.createStatement();
```

*DAVE-PC\SQLEXP/" is the name of my database. The username and password are windows authentication.

My second question is if I can't access the database like this, Is there any virtual server (compatible with microsoft SQL) that I can copy the database there and access it from the?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your mistake is in userName. for your PC you can try LOCALHOST or 127.0.0.1  Perhaps you would try this method to connect:

try{

server = "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=STORESQL;selectMethod=cursor";
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(server,"dave",password);

```
 }catch(SQLException e){
     System.out.println(e);
 }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
     System.out.println(e);
 }
```

Comment: I still couldn't connect to it so I ended up just writing the code in SQL and execute in SQL server directly.